# Artifacts in image after super resolution using delaunay triangulation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, resolution, visual-artifacts

i have to do super resolution of two low resolution images to obtain a high resolution image.

2nd image is taken as base image and the first image is registered with respect to it . i used SURF algorithm for image registration . A Delaunay triangulation is constructed over the points using a built-in MATLAB delaunay function . The HR grid of size is constructed for a prespecified resolution enhancement factor R Then HR algorithm for interpolating the pixel values on the HR grid is summarized next.

HR Algorithm Steps: 1. Construct the Delaunay triangulation over the set of scattered vertices in the irregularly sampled raster formed from the LR frames.

```
Estimate the gradient vector at each vertex of the triangulation by calculating the unit normal vector of neighbouring vector using cross product method.Sum of the unit normal vector of each triangle multiplied by its area is divided by summation of area of all neighbouring triangles to get the vertex normal.

Approximate each triangle patch in the triangulation by a continuous and, possibly, a continuously differentiable surface, subject to some smoothness constraint. Bivariate polynomials or splines could be the approximants as explained below.
Set the resolution enhancement factor along the horizontal and vertical directions and then calculate the pixel value at each regularly spaced HR grid point to construct the initial HR image
```

now i have the results shown below

now for one kind of data set i get this result that has a few pixels black and wite in a random manner for the other type i get thin parallel lines all over image after super resolution the results are attached

[image: these two are base and unregistered image]
[image: second dataset after interpolation thin parallel lines with same code]

[image: this is first unregistered frame![this is second unregistered frame![thirs unregistered frame]
[image: this is super resolved image]

any one can tell me the reason, i have figured out may be its demosaicing but i am not sure,because i dnt have much understanding of it , moreover can it be a bug in my code but it behaves different for different images, i have increased the size by super resolution twice.

Comment: You may have more luck at dsp.stackexchange, since this is really a image processing question.

Comment: ok i was not knowing thanku i will post there

Comment: i cnt find any help there as well :(

Comment: It's difficult to know what's going wrong with your code without seeing the code, and it'll be a pain to wade through pages of code to find the bug. I thought that maybe this is a problem somebody has already experienced; debugging custom software is unfortunately something the programmer will often have to do themselves.